# How can I use Keynote to present a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, conversion, presentations, iwork-keynote

I want to use Apple Keynote on Mac OS X to present a PDF document (which was made using Adobe InDesign).
Especially the next-page-view is handy.
As Keynote can only import single PDF pages, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Harvey Mudd College made a free application, which converts a PDF to a Keynote document: [PDF to Keynote](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/freesoftware/pdftokeynote.html).